# JavaScript Objects: Why Doesn't This Work?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I wrote the following code. Instead of giving me an answer, it outputs NaN. I would like the code to return the weights of John and Mark. Please explain.

```
'use script';

//  Declaring variables
var infoJohn;
var infoMark;
var bmiCalculator;
var higherBmi;

bmiCalculator = function (height, mass) {
    var calculatedBmi;

    calculatedBmi = mass / (height * height);
    return calculatedBmi;
};

infoJohn = {
    name: 'John',
    mass: 85,
    height: 110,
    bmi: bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass)
};

infoMark = {
    name: 'Mark',
    mass: 120,
    height: 85,
    bmi: bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass)
};

console.log('Mark\'s BMI: ' + infoMark.bmi, 'John\'s BMI: ' + infoJohn.bmi, 
'\n\n');
```

Comment: `'use strict'` instead of `'use script'`

Comment: It is a context problem, `this` doesn't refer to what you think it refers to.

Comment: He already declared the variables before @gazdagergo

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap `bmiCalculator` call to a `function` because otherwise `this` refers to a global (`window`) context.

This should work:

```js
var bmiCalculator = function(height, mass) {
  var calculatedBmi;

  calculatedBmi = mass / (height * height);
  return calculatedBmi;
};

var infoJohn = {
  name: 'John',
  mass: 85,
  height: 110,
  bmi: function() {
    return bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass);
  }
};

var infoMark = {
  name: 'Mark',
  mass: 120,
  height: 85,
  bmi: function() {
    return bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass);
  }
};

//higherBmi = function (h)

console.log('Mark\'s BMI: ' + infoMark.bmi(), 'John\'s BMI: ' + infoJohn.bmi(),
  '\n\n');
```

Comment: Could you add a little explanation?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal i've updated my answer. Thanks for an advice.

Comment: This works but you've changed the `bmi` property to a function.

Comment: @Titus yes, it's one of the ways to resolve OP problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) if you want to refer to the object using `this`.

Here is an example:

```js
'use strict'
//  Declaring variables
var infoJohn;
var infoMark;
var bmiCalculator;
var higherBmi;

bmiCalculator = function (height, mass) {
    var calculatedBmi;

    calculatedBmi = mass / (height * height);
    return calculatedBmi;
};

infoJohn = {
    name: 'John',
    mass: 85,
    height: 110,
    get bmi(){ 
      return bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass);
    }
};

infoMark = {
    name: 'Mark',
    mass: 120,
    height: 85,
    get bmi(){ 
      return bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass);
    }
};

console.log('Mark\'s BMI: ' + infoMark.bmi, 'John\'s BMI: ' + infoJohn.bmi, 
'\n\n');
```

Unlike in your example where you're trying to set the `bmi` property when the object is created, here, the `bmiCalculator` function is called every time you access the `bmi` property on one of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```js
'use strict';

//  Declaring variables
var infoJohn;
var infoMark;
var bmiCalculator;
var higherBmi;

var bmiCalculator = function(height, mass) {
  return mass / (height * height);
};

var infoJohn = {
  name: 'John',
  mass: 85,
  height: 110,
  get bmi() {
    return bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass)
  }
};

var infoMark = {
  name: 'Mark',
  mass: 120,
  height: 85,
  get bmi() {
    return bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass)
  }
};

console.log(`Mark's BMI: ${infoMark.bmi}, John's BMI: ${infoJohn.bmi}\n\n`);
```

Few things to note here:

The `bmiCalculator` can simply be a return since it does basic calculation.
The `infoJohn` and `infoMark` bmi functions are now [getters](https://coryrylan.com/blog/javascript-es6-class-syntax) which allows them to be called without the parentheses and also in this way we keep the `this` context when returning the `bmiCalculator`

On the end we use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 1):

The way you instantiate the object and utilise `this` is the issue. You are using an object literal and at the point you assign a value to the properties, `this` refers to the `window` (or `global` in Node).

```
infoJohn = {
  ...
  bmi:  ... // here - this does not refer to infoJohn
}
```

Your code could be amended to assign the BMI property after assigning the other properties so that they exist on the object before running through the `bmiCalculator` function - but you'd still not use `this`.

```
infoJohn = {
  name: 'John',
  mass: 85,
  height: 110
};
infoJohn.bmi = bmiCalculator(infoJohn.height, infoJohn.mass)
```

If you want to use `this`, then it must be within the correct context. There are some other answers here which provide BMI as either a function or as a getter which are probably a better way to go - they will always show an updated BMI whenever the height or mass change.

```
  // as a function property
  bmi: function(){ return this.mass / (this.height*this.height) }
  // or as a getter
  get bmi(){ return this.mass / (this.height*this.height) }
```

Another way to rewrite what you have is into a more object-oriented way. e.g.

```
var Person = function(name, mass, height){
  this.name = name
  this.mass = mass
  this.height = height
  // assign a value as a static value - does not update
  this.bmi = mass / (height * height)
}

var infoJohn = new Person('John',85,110)
var infoMark = new Person('Mark',120,85)

console.log('Mark\'s BMI: ' + infoMark.bmi, 'John\'s BMI: ' + infoJohn.bmi, '\n\n');

infoMark.mass = 110
console.log('Mark\'s new BMI: '+ inforMark.bmi) // will not update
```

Comment: Very helpful. Explanation was great also. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a variable that you didn't define before! put a `var` before your variable definition so program should know what are you talking about. Also you cannot call functions directly in your object! you should use another function to call the function you want. like this:

```
var infoJohn = {
    name: 'John',
    mass: 85,
    height: 110,
    bmi: function() {
        return bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass);
    }
};
```

So you have to use `bmi` as a function after that:

```
console.log('Mark\'s BMI: ' + infoMark.bmi(), 'John\'s BMI: ' + infoJohn.bmi(), '\n\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use **getter** function.

```
infoJohn = {
    name: 'John',
    mass: 85,
    height: 110,
    bmi: bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass) // . <<--This is incorrect
};
```

Here, the **this** object is not pointing to your `infoJohn` object as you are expecting. Instead, it is pointing to the global `window` object (if you are using client-side JS). And, since there is no `window.height` and `window.mass` property it would pass `undefined` as the parameter in your 
`bmiCalculator` function. Mathematical operations on non-number values like `undefined` results in `NaN`. Hence, you are getting the same. You can correct this as follows:

```js
bmiCalculator = function (height, mass) {
    var calculatedBmi;

    calculatedBmi = mass / (height * height);
    return calculatedBmi;
};

infoJohn = {
    name: 'John',
    mass: 85,
    height: 110,
    get bmi() { return bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass)}
};

console.log(infoJohn.bmi);
```

Comment: @Jachi You're always welcome. :) Kindly upvote (+1) my answer if you found it helpful. Also, approve the answer that you found as the most suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

More elegant way...

```
const bmiCalculator = (height, mass) => mass / (height * height);

const infoJohn = {
    name: 'John',
    mass: 85,
    height: 110,
    get bmi() {
        return bmiCalculator(this.height, this.mass);
    }
};

console.log(infoJohn.bmi);
```